# Rails -- Select records based on defined attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, records

I want to select records for a model based on a defined attribute.

I have a Docket model. Dockets have many Statuses. (I want to record each status change to maintain status change history and some meta data on each status change.) Each Status has a code attribute.

Each Docket has a defined attribute: currentstatus (self.Statuses.last.code). I want to select all Dockets that have currentstatus == 1. Because it is a defined attribute, I cannot use Dockets.where(:currentstatus => 1).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can used a **named_scope** in your docket.rb:

```
named_scope :find_by_currentstatus, lambda {|currentstatus| 
  {:conditions => {:currentstatus => 1}}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try an sql approach

```
Docket.where('(SELECT statuses.currentstatus FROM statuses WHERE statuses.docket_id = dockets.id ORDER BY statuses.created_at DESC LIMIT 1) = ?', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Docket.joins(:statuses).where("statuses.currentstatus = 1")
```

#### Update

Try the following:

```
Docket.includes(:statuses).where("(statuses.id = (select max(statuses2.id) from statuses statuses2 where statuses2.docket_id = dockets.id)) AND (statuses.currenstatus = 1)")
```

Comment: currentstatus is the attribute of docket :)

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky one as you have only two really ugly options and one that's a bit clunky:

a) Load everything and filter it in memory (don't do that!)

b) Translate the logic inside your `current_status` method into an SQL Query and have the logic duplicated in your `current_status` method and your `search_for_current_status` methods.

c) Duplicate the data (meaning, when current_status changes you set a flag on Docket that you can then query with `where`.

NEVER ever do a - consider b if the current_status method is something simple (you could define it in a scope method on the Docket model like this)

```
class Docket < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.open
    # so some magic here with joins on the statuses table
  end
end
```

c is basically just a de-normalization of your data for query purposes. you could put that into the original model, or you could create a special table (you may even refresh that table automatically through a cron-job or some other trigger - maybe ActiveRecord after_save callback in the `Status` model)